# Routing Plain FAQ Typo3 11

Tags: yaml, typo3, url-routing

I would like to make a readable URL for the extension Plain FAQ Typo3 . This is my file.yaml.  Help me please: Where is error ?

```
PlainFaq:
  type: Extbase
  extension: PlainFaq
  plugin: Pidetail
  routes:
      - { routePath: '/detail/{faq}', _controller: 'Faq::detail', _arguments: {'faq': '@widget_0/currentPage'}  }
  defaultController: 'Faq::detail'
  defaults:
    page: '1'
  requirements:
    page: '\d+'
```

Comment: all widget Functionality has been removed in typo3 11 so are you shure the extension still uses the @widget_0 argument: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.0/Breaking-92529-AllFluidWidgetFunctionalityRemoved.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use this configuration for the detail plugin

```
FaqDetailPlugin:
  type: Extbase
  limitToPages:
    - 30
  extension: PlainFaq
  plugin: Pidetail
  routes:
    -
      routePath: '/{faq_title}'
      _controller: 'Faq::detail'
      _arguments:
        faq_title: faq
  defaultController: 'Faq::detail'
  aspects:
    faq_title:
      type: PersistedAliasMapper
      tableName: tx_plainfaq_domain_model_faq
      routeFieldName: slug
```

You must adapt `limitToPages` setting to the TYPO3 page uid, where the detail plugin of the extension is configured.